# What cell phones (feature phones, not smart phones) work well with Ubuntu?

Tags: sync, phone

I'm in the market for a new cell phone soon, and I'd like for it to work well with Ubuntu. I don't use my phone for much--just calls, texts, and the occasional photo. It would be nice if it could also do these things (highest priority first):

1. Be cheap
2. Sync (or at least manually transfer) contact data with Ubuntu
3. Sync (or at least manually transfer) photos with Ubuntu
4. Connect to Ubuntu via something like a mini-usb cable, rather than requiring a vendor-specific cable
5. Sync (or at least manually transfer) ringtones and such with Ubuntu (I doubt I'll ever use this, which is why it is last)

What phones best meet these criteria? It it matters, I am on Verizon in the USA.

Comment: This is also off topic since it's a hardware recommendation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gnome-phone-manager and Gnocky rely on http://www.gnokii.org/ (Wammu and Gammu are forks of that) all Nokia are fully supported, others have basic support (phonebook).

Answer (score 1):

try Wammu, almost all of cellphones are working, but that also depends on conection posibilities..